# can't assign two style in different tag

Tags: html, css

When I use`class="top-menu"` and `class="pull-right"` these two together I get the result is the image is pull-right but the background color does not change to black, What is wrong with my code?

If I delete the `class="pull-right"` the background color becomes black

```css
.top-menu {
  background-color: black;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="container-fluid top-menu">
      <img src="..." alt="Awsome_Ticket_Logo" class="pull-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It looks like you use Bootstrap. Which version?

Answer (score 3):

When you float something, it is no longer part of its parent's bounding box. Since there is nothing else in your `top-menu` parent, the bounding box will be considered empty and it will have a height of 0.

A common solution to this is to add a clearfix to the parent. This will make it include whatever space was taken up by its floated children:

```css
.top-menu {
    background-color: black;
}

.pull-right{
    float: right;
}

.top-menu:after {
    content: "";
    clear: right;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container-fluid top-menu">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Awsome_Ticket_Logo" class="pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when things float the container becomes empty, you can use a clearfix: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/nrysp61w/18/

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of developers has this problem with their code. Normally, This issue comes with bad styling of your page structure. Also, the first solution that many developers come with is to use `clear: both;` styling in pseudo. But, I think if you learn how to style like a good developer you will never need to use `clear`. Just start to write your page in a normal and standard way.

When you give a `float` to the child of a parent which doesn't have a `float` property, The parent will lose its height (if its the only child of that parent). The best way to avoid this happening its to divide the sections of your page and give them a good floating. This way you'll never need to use `clear` styling.

```css
header,
.header-top,
.top-menu {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.top-menu {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
  <header>
      <div class="header-top">
          <div class="container-fluid top-menu">
              <img src="" alt="Awsome_Ticket_Logo" class="pull-right">
          </div>
      </div>
  </header>
```